# Writing every item to file in a long running Python script?

Tags: python-3.x, list, file

I have a Python script that searches for every image on a hard drive, gets its size, some metadata and hash. The end result for a single file is a tuple, for example:

```
file_tuple = (fullpath ; filename ; filesize ; some_meta ; hash)
```

I want to have all tuples in a single file_list and finally in a file.

My script works for small folders but if I run it on the whole drive whatever happens (memory error, OSError, runs forever, needing to restart kernel etc.) all the "work" is lost.

So I want to be able to save results as soon as any file has gone through the process. If the script breaks for whatever reason I can simply pick up from the point of last failure.

The solution that I had in mind is to put within the loop, in pseudocode:

- open file
- write 1 line
- close file

Like:

```
with open('Files.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(file_tuple + '\n')
```

Is this a good solution or am I missing some bigger concept (hobbyist here)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A real program would probably use some form of database for that kind of storage, such as [sqlite](https://www.sqlite.org/index.html), but if an ordinary file works for you, that's fine as well. Note, though that:

- you will need to open the file in `'a'` (append) mode, otherwise each open will eradicate the previous content
- `file_tuple + '\n'` probably won't work because a tuple is not a string; you will need something like `f.write(f"{file_tuple}\n")`.

There is a possibility that opening and closing a file will be slow, but that depends on the operating system and the other things that your program does - you should measure it. If it is too slow, then you'll probably want to open the file only once, and just `write()` the tuple.

Comment: Thanks. That with file_tuple + 'n' is not as important. It is a technical detail. I would have realized it. It was more a conceptual question and you answered it. Thanks also for technicalities with writing to a file.